# How to automate Kafka Testing

Tags: java, automated-tests, apache-kafka

We have developed a system using kafka to queue the data and later consume that data to place orders for users.
We have tested certain things manually, but now our aim is automate the process.
Is there any client available to test it? I found out ways to Unit test it using kafka client itself, but my aim is to test the system as whole.

EDIT: our purpose is just API testing i.e., just the back-end, not the UI

Comment: In my experience so far, testing a kafka-based system in standalone environment (single kafka broker, single zookeeper, single partition, few consumers/producers running sequentially/synchronously) works fine. You may run into synchronization and timing issues with offsets and all in a live environment where your system produces & consumes in real time and you're trying to tap into the bus to validate the data going through it. That's for the case wehre live env has multiple brokers, zookeepers, partitions, producers & consumers, and possibly asynchronous flow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can start Kafka programmatically in your integration test, Kafka uses Zookeeper so firsly look at Zookeeper [TestingServer](https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-test/src/main/java/org/apache/curator/test/TestingServer.java) - instance of this class creates and starts the Zk server using the given port.

Next look at [KafkaServerStartable.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7130da90a9ee9e6fb4beb2a2a6ab05c06c9bfac4/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaServerStartable.scala), you have to provide configuration that points to your in memory Zk server and invoke `startup()` method, here is some code:

```
import kafka.server.KafkaConfig; 
import kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable;
import java.util.Properties;

public KafkaTest() {
    Properties properties = createProperties();
    KafkaConfig kafkaConfig = new KafkaConfig(properties);
    KafkaServerStartable kafka = new KafkaServerStartable(kafkaConfig);
    kafka.startup();
}
```

Hope these help:)

Comment: hi, thanks,  may be I lack understanding over the topic, but our kafka is deployed over a remote server, will I be able to access it by the way you suggested from my local machine ..

Comment: I suggest you to start Kafka before your test suite, in this case you don't have to connect to remote server. I think that is better solution because your tests don't depends on external resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for integration-testing or end-to-end testing by bringing up Kafka in a `docker` container. If you use *Apache* `kafka-clients:2.1.0`, then you don't need to deal with *ZooKeeper* at the API level while producing or consuming the records.

Dockerizing Kafka, and testing helps to cover the scenarios in a single node as well as multi-node Kafka cluster. This way you don't have to test against Mock/In-Memory Kafka once, then real Kafka later. This can be done using [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/).

If you have too many test scenarios to cover, you can go for [Kafka Declarative Testing](https://github.com/authorjapps/hello-kafka-stream-testing#kafka-testing-hello-world-examples) like `docker-compose` style, by which you can eliminate the Kafka client API coding.

Checkout some handy examples here for validating [produce](https://github.com/authorjapps/hello-kafka-stream-testing/tree/master/src/test/resources/kafka/produce) and [consume](https://github.com/authorjapps/hello-kafka-stream-testing/tree/master/src/test/resources/kafka/consume).

TestContainers project also supports docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to implement end to end tests starting from messages. Me and some people from recently made a research for libraries, tools and frameworks to test Event-driven systems using Kafka.

We found Zerocode which is an automated API testing using declarative language like JSON or YAML. It support REST, SOAP and what we are interested, Messaging. It sends and consumes messages from topics and make assertions in the end, easy to learn and use. Here is the link for more details [Zerocode](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode). It seems like a good option although we are starting using it.

You will need to have Kafka brokers and the dependencies running to make this solution to work, but nothing like a docker compose and/or some scripts to bring a environment for tests.

Another way is to implement your own project with Kafka libraries and use the libraries to send and receive messages in the tests.

Unfortunately we couldn't find more options available out there. Kafka has a proposition to create a [test kit](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-139%3A+Kafka+TestKit+library) but it's not in progress yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the approach described by Pavel does not work for Kafka 2.8+ anymore. However, I could make our end-to-end tests with Kafka 3.2 work using the approach taken by [KarelDB](https://github.com/rayokota/kareldb/blob/master/kareldb-core/src/test/java/io/kareldb/utils/ClusterTestHarness.java):

```
Properties props = TestUtils.createBrokerConfig(
        brokerId,
        zkConnect,
        false,
        false,
        TestUtils.RandomPort(),
        noInterBrokerSecurityProtocol,
        noFile,
        EMPTY_SASL_PROPERTIES,
        true,
        false,
        TestUtils.RandomPort(),
        false,
        TestUtils.RandomPort(),
        false,
        TestUtils.RandomPort(),
        Option.<String>empty(),
        1,
        false,
        1,
        (short) 1
);
KafkaConfig config = KafkaConfig.fromProps(props);
KafkaServer server = TestUtils.createServer(config, Time.SYSTEM);

// `createServer` will also start your Kafka server.

// To shutdown:
server.shutdown();
```